# question about interfaces and inheritance

Tags: erc-1155, interfaces, inheritance

I am building my own application for an erc1155 dapp but have some questions about interfaces and inheritance. How do you re-declare functionality that you inherit from another contract? Also, how do you even implement interfaces in your code? I understand importing files and the "is" keyword in your contract header, but how do you actually USE an interface? As in are you supposed to rewrite functions that you inherit from interfaces or other imported contracts? Or just leave them alone after declaring you inherited? Sorry if this is such a silly question I am just very excited yet overwhelmed on now starting to make my own projects unguided haha. Thank you!

**Edit**:

```
function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC115) external 
{ 
    IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT) .safeTransferFrom(); 
}

function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC1155) external view returns(address)
{ 
    return IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT).safeTransferFrom(); 
} //Functions redecalred in my base contract.

function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC1155) external 
{ 
    IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT).safeTransferFrom();
}

function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC1155) external view returns(address) 
{
    IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT).safeTransferFrom();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No question is a silly question.

[Interfaces](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#interfaces) are used to interact with different contracts.

Inside interfaces, you only declare the functionality of the function you wish to implement so that you can re-use it in different contracts.

 It's used for light-weight importing code, instead of importing the whole contract.

Here's an example from [Solidity by Example](https://solidity-by-example.org/interface/)

First, you define the contract containing the basic functionality:

```
contract Counter {
    uint public count;

    function increment() external {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Now, to use this function, we declare an interface, containing **only** the basic structure of the function:

```
interface ICounter {
    function count() external view returns (uint);

    function increment() external;
}
```

Now, to use these functions stated in the base contract and re-declared in the interface, we simply call the interface with the address of the contract containing the code and return it with the interface call, as follows:

```
contract MyContract {
    // "address _counter" here is the address of 
    // the first declared contract, called "Counter".
    function incrementCounter(address _counter) external {
        // In the next line, we call the interface with 
        // the base contract address, and call the function we wish to use.
        ICounter(_counter).increment();
    }

    function getCount(address _counter) external view returns (uint) {
        return ICounter(_counter).count();
    }
}
```

The owner of Solidity by Example also has a YouTube channel I recommend, [here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbjyc-VQaQo) of him explaining about Interfaces.

Please let me know if I've explained it properly or if you have further questions.
This is indeed a concept that takes some time to grasp. I suggest you try to implement it in your code to understand better how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I actually do understnad the concept of what interfaces are and how inheritance works however its the actual implementation that is a bit confusing to me(as in how to actually use it in your code). I am trying to use an erc1155 interface and inheritance but again am a bit confused with the syntax and "how to". When I redeclare functions I redecalre them in my base function correct? So I basically inly use the functions from the interface that I want to use and not the whole thing?

Comment: Paste some code, so I can help you more specifically.

Generally, you have the first contract with the code you wish to re-use.
Then, in your interface you copy the base of the function, and lastly, you call the interface name, with the address of the contract, and finish with the function itself.

Comment: Ah ok I see. I think I may have done the opposite actually. I will paste the code to my smart contract here. Hope it reads well.                                                                              function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC115) external {
     IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT) .safeTransferFrom();
     }


    function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC1155) external view returns(address){
      return IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT).safeTransferFrom();
  }                                             //Functions redecalred in my base contract.

Comment: Kind of hard to read it from a comment, edit your original post with block code formatting.

Comment: function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC1155) external {                                                            IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT).safeTransferFrom() };                                                                                  function safeTransferFrom(address _IERC1155) external view returns(address) {                       IERC1155(_SpiderVerseNFT).safeTransferFrom(){;                                                               
 I inherited these functions from the open zepellin IERC1155 and declared them in my base contract named SpiderVerseNFT.

Comment: I meant in the question itself, not it the comments; anyway - I've added that.

Comment: It seems you're not using the function declaration correctly.
Also, I don't quite understand what's in the original contract and what's not.
Please notice that you should not use the address of the interface, but the address of the contract inside the call of the interface, like in the example I've shown above in my answer.